# Oracle Pro*C : Handling end of fetch cursor

Tags: c, oracle, error-handling, cursor, oracle11g

I can't figure out the problem on my code :

```
/* Declare a cursor for the FETCH statement. */
EXEC SQL DECLARE customer_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE 
WHERE CUSTOMER_CARD_NUM = :argv[1];

if ( sqlca.sqlcode != 0 )
{
        printf("Declare cursor failed\n");
        return( sqlca.sqlcode );
}
EXEC SQL OPEN customer_cursor;
if ( sqlca.sqlcode != 0 )
{
        printf("Open cursor failed\n");
        return( sqlca.sqlcode );
}
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND GOTO no_match;

for ( ;; )
{
    /* Fetching data */
    EXEC SQL FETCH customer_cursor 
        INTO :var_customer_id, :var_customer_name;
    if ( sqlca.sqlcode != 0 )
    {
            EXEC SQL CLOSE cust_data_cursor;
            return ( sqlca.sqlcode );
    }

    /* Doing some stuff here */
    processing_customer();

}
EXEC SQL CLOSE customer_cursor;

/* Handling the no data found here */    
no_match:

      printf("NO CUSTOMER MATCHING THIS CARD_NUM\n");
      /* Some stuff */
      ......
      return 1;
```

My query is supposed to return just one row or nothing, when nothing is returned all is ok, **but when ther's a matching, the function processing_customer is executed and the strange is that the no_match is executed too**.

Thanks for helping me to fix that.

Comment: Why not? this is the traditional way to do this. You have a better idea?

Comment: Let me ask in a different way.. What is the purpose of doing the cursor?

Comment: To check if my query return a record from the db or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roger Cornejo suggests, you need a way to *not* execute the 'no match' section if there is a match. `no_match:` is just a label so there's nothing to tell your code not to execute that section. You either need to return before that label, or `goto` something after it. You also need to close the cursor in the no-match scenario.

But this seems unnecessarily messy and as @Arion hinted you don't need an explicit cursor for this - just do a `select into` and catch the exception.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME
    INTO :var_customer_id, :var_customer_name
    FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE 
    WHERE CUSTOMER_CARD_NUM = :argv[1];

if (sqlca.sqlcode == 1403)
{
    printf("NO CUSTOMER MATCHING THIS CARD_NUM\n");
    /* Some stuff */
    ......
    return 1;
}
if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
{
    return ( sqlca.sqlcode );
}

/* Doing some stuff here */
processing_customer();
```

You've said there will be zero or one rows; if there are more than one you'll get a too-many-rows error (ORA-02112).

Answer (score 0):

add GOTO  after "EXEC SQL CLOSE customer_cursor;"

Comment: I added a new GOTO as you suggested but still get a strange behavior at the end of the cursor!

Answer (score 0):

Change your label "no_match" to "no_more_records" and you'll realize why it runs 2 times:

a) when there are no records, the FETCH raises the NOT FOUND condition inmediatly and therefore will go to the label "no_more_records"

b) when there is one (or more) record(s), the FETCH is executed returning the first record.

Then the

> if ( sqlca.sqlcode != 0 )

evaluates to false (in fact, only useful to trap other problems) and then

> processing_customer();

After it, the FETCH run again (by the infinity for) and behave as in (a): no_more_records condition arrives.